# Min IF function : SAP Dashboard

Tags: excel, xcelsius

I have calculated Minimum value using `MIN` and `IF` functions in Excel for the below mentioned data using `Array` function. Below is the screen shot for your reference:

[image]

This works absolutely fine, but when I try to write this in SAP Dashboard (Xcelsius), this array function is not working properly.

Is there any other way to achieve the results. All I want is `min` value of each team. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this question. I used "Sum if" function as the status is always 1 or 0 : =IF(SUMIF(C:C,Q4,G:G)>=6,1,0)

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Good workaround - note that you could use COUNTIFS instead, as it allows you to count the number of rows where particular columns match particular criteria. Something like: |=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,Q4,G:G,1)>=6,1,0)| This would work if the values were something other than 1 / 0 [though not nececessary in your case as your solution works fine with your present dataset].